# How to get a reference of tableView from another class in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My tableView has the IBOutlet and it's delegate tied to my firstViewController.

I'm trying to dirrectly access the tableView from another ViewController.

For example, if I want to find out the number of rows in section 0 from another ViewController I do:

```
  let firstViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstViewController") as FirstViewController

  println(firstViewController.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0))
```

But I get an error when I run the code
***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

Comment: Are the ViewControllers connected with NavigationController or TabBarController ?

Comment: yes, they are connected with NavigationController

Comment: Does your tableView have a datasource set?

Comment: yes, I connected the data source and the delegate of the tableview to the firstViewController using the interface builder by dragging it.
What are you trying to say? If I've declared it correctly I would've no problem accessing it from any controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the properties from the previous view controller in the Navigation controller, then this works pervectly:

**Method for getting the previous controller in the navigation controller**

```
func backViewController() -> UIViewController
{
    var numberOfViewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count

    if numberOfViewControllers < 2
    {
        return UIViewController()
    }
    else
    {
        return self.navigationController!.viewControllers[numberOfViewControllers! - 2] as UIViewController
    }
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
   let cont = backViewController() as YourPreviousViewController
   println(cont.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)) //prints the number of rows in the previous ViewController's tableView
```

**Or for the first viewController in the NavigationController:**

```
let firstViewController = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first as FirstViewController
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually just did this

      
`let firstViewController = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first as FirstViewController`

Comment: Even better :), I'll add this to the anwser;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the datasource to get the number of rows instead of the tableView.

Comment: what if I want to refresh the data or animate the rows I just inserted using the other controller?

Comment: You can use the NSNotificationCenter to do this, just subscribe the viewController with the tableView to an event and then post this event from your secondary controller once you are done adding data:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a class which confirms to UITableViewDataSource, and then create an instance and share the instance for the two view controllers.